# Is there any way to draw a artificial neural network connections in a nice way? [Javascript]

Tags: javascript, drawing, artificial-intelligence

So I've been working with neural networks and artificial intelligence for a while and what I'm trying to do right now is, from a genotype I have (a sum of sensors, neurons and actuators) draw how the neural network is (with recurrent/recursive connections being showed nicely, etc.)

What I have done now in javascript is this: I know, its ugly
[image]
I have achieved this using SigmaJs a Javascript node drawing library, but I think it's still ugly, and what I'm looking for is a node drawing library that can achieve recursive connections in a nice way (right now I'm drawing them with a red color as you can see on the image).

I have examined a lot of GitHub repositories and websites that can be helpful but aren't worth since they aren't that nice.

Has anyone got an idea of what can I use, in javascript? If not, in any other language, how can I achieve what I want?

Regards, Miguel